# How to write two dictionaries into an output file "txt"

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is actually a 4 part question:

1) Returns a dictionary, which each key is word length and its value is the number of words with that length.
e.g. if the input file's text is `"Hello Python people Welcome to the world of Python"`, then the dictionary should be: 
    {2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 1}

2) Returns a dictionary, which each key is a word and its value is the number of occurrences of that word.
    e.g. {'hello': 1, 'of': 1, 'people': 1, 'python': 2, 'the': 1, 'to': 
    1,'welcome': 1, 'world': 1}

I already completed the first two parts using the following codes below.

```
def make_length_wordcount(x):
    filename=x+'.txt'
    infile=open(filename)
    wordlist=infile.read().split()
    counter1={}
    for word in wordlist:
        if len(word) in counter1:
            counter1[len(word)]+=1
        else:
            counter1[len(word)]=1
    infile.close()
    print(counter1)

def make_word_count(string):
    words=string.lower().split()
    dictionary={}
    for word in words:
        dictionaryp[word]=0
    for word in words:
        dictionary[word]+=1
    print(dictionary)
```

I'M HAVING TROUBLE FIGURING OUT HOW TO DO PART 3) AND 4):

3) Uses the two functions above - `make_length_wordcount()` and `make_word_count()` - to construct (i) length-wordcount dictionary and (ii) word count dictionary.

Opens a new output file `"FILE_analyzed_FIRST_LAST.txt"` and write two dictionaries into this file (in the format below). the output file name is
`"test_analyzed_HYUN_KANG.txt"` and it should contain the following lines:

```
Words of length 2 : 2
Words of length 3 : 1
Words of length 5 : 2
Words of length 6 : 3
Words of length 7 : 1
to : 1
of : 1
people : 1
the : 1
python : 2
welcome : 1
hello : 1
world : 1
```

4) In "hw2_FIRST_LAST.py" file, run the analyze_text() function three times with the following inputs:
     `a. "nasdaq.txt"`
     `b. "raven.txt"`
     `c. "frankenstein.txt"`

Your hw2.py code should generate the following three files: 
    `"nasdaq_analyzed_FIRST_LAST.txt"`, `"raven_analyzed_FIRST_LAST.txt"`, 
    `"frankenstein_analyzed_FIRST_LAST.txt"`

My instructor didn't really teach us anything about writing files, so this is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

A few things first:
1) you can avoid the

```py
        if len(word) in counter1:
            counter1[len(word)]+=1
        else:
            counter1[len(word)]=1
```

by using defaultdict or Counter from the collections module:

```py
counter1 = defaultdict(int)
for word in wordlist:
    counter1[word] += 1
```

Same applies to `make_word_count`:

```py
def make_word_count(string):
    words = string.lower().split()
    dictionary = Counter(words)
    print(dictionary.most_common(10))
```

For your 3rd points (I didn't test, but you get the idea):

```py
def make_text_wordlen(counter1):
    text = ''
    for wordlen, value in counter1.items():
        text += f'Words of length {wordlen} : {value}\n'
    with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)
```

```py
def make_text_wordcount(dictionary):
    text = ''
    for word, count in dictionary.items():
        text += f'{word} : {count}\n'
    with open('your_file.txt', 'a') as f:  # 'a' parameter to append to existing file
        f.write(text)
```

I'll let you figure out the 4th point.